# How to resolve UNC file issue in SSIS

Tags: winforms, etl, ssis, unc

I was trying to import an xls file on UNC folder using SSIS and got the below error:

> [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Is there any way to resolve this issue without shortening the file name length?
This is not an access issue, as I have all the access to the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest mapping the network drive and path to a local drive letter?

```
net use t: \\myserver\my\very\long\path
```

In the package, then just use the mapped drive as file connectionstring.